# Unjustified downvotes, tag stinginess, and general site dysfunction

Tags: discussion

Several of my questions have been the target of multiple downvotes that I see as inappropriate and unjustified for certain questions. The latest example is [this now perfectly valid question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/295540/how-can-i-style-the-gutenberg-module-editor), which I'd edited to meet the site standards as a result of following instructions on the [Drupal Answers Help Center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans). The edited question and answer subsequently received two downvotes today, coinciding with leymannx's comment. [Here is another perfectly good question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294423/error-private-files-directory-not-fully-protected) that's received numerous unexplained downvotes.

Since I joined starting as a Drupal novice, this particular Stack Exchange site has struck me as dysfunctional and unusually critical. Some of the downvotes appear justified, especially once learning of actual duplicates or my initial assumptions or ignorance become evident. However, there seems to be a preponderance of unhelpful, often unexplained and piled-on downvotes as well as votes to close, without reasonable attention to subsequent question-edit revisions. This can only serve to drive away new users from the site while accomplishing little to anything actually improving the site's quality.

Another strange quirk to this site is the apparent distaste from those with reputation for adding new tags and rejecting new ones, for example the lacking Gutenberg tag. For comparison, the Wordpress stack exchange site has about 800 tags, whereas this site has about 150.

**Case in point** (and how meta meta and recursive is this!? Not to mention unsurprising):

[image: Meta meta]

Here's another example of what seems to me to be a [reasonable question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294423/error-private-files-directory-not-fully-protected). To boot, it ended up becoming an editor war over tagging it with `9`, when I wasn't asking about Drupal 9, along with unexplained downvotes.

I wouldn't care so much superficially, but I've been prevented from posting questions until the system's perceived quality of them increases.

Comment: I don't agree with the statement about tags (SO has 62000+ tags, what does that say about the WP site?), but I feel your pain on the other things. You've been caught in an unfortunate loop; the system tells you to improve existing questions, but at the same time changing the meaning of a question that someone has already invested time in answering, in such a way that invalidates that effort, is also not desirable. Then there's the fact that he original question probably wasn't a great fit for the site anyway, which muddies it for everyone, you included. This is quite a specific situation...

Comment: ...personally I'd recommend taking this one on the chin, and not putting it down to a more endemic problem with the whole community. I'll also say that I don't, again personally, agree with the voting that happened after the edit either. There are other ways to express dissatisfaction if a question has changed meaning (comments, flags) without using votes that maybe weren't focused on the quality of the question but rather its evolution

Comment: Tags on DA only get introduced after being discussed on Meta. It can be bothersome to take that route but on the long run it makes curating the site much easier. To me it felt that in most of your early questions you did try to game the system. I think there were questions showing only little efforts, then got self-answered immediately thereafter. WPSE is difficult to compare to DA in my experience. WPSE to me feels like 100 new users a day while 50% of them are asking support questions for off-topic premium plugins/themes.

Comment: @Clive I chose Wordpress purposefully because it is of such a similar scope to Drupal vs. Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Clive with respect to the whole community; of course it doesn't reflect on each individual, but as a whole, the site in my experience has been as described. I only cited this one question as an example, though it now looks like we have a second example per my new screenshot. (Though I do recognize people typically particularly enjoy downvoting meta questions.)

Comment: @leymannx I appreciate your feedback. I'm not sure what "gaming the system" means, but my normal approach to new platforms is to first Google/check documentation, then start writing a question without submitting for a Stack Exchange site, which often turns up the right answer either via duplicate question or just helps me refine my Google search after thinking it through. If the question isn't already on the site and I've discovered the answer, I'll post it along with the answer. And as you likely know, self-answered questions are valued by the founder of SO and encouraged by the community.

Comment: @leymannx I'm not sure where you're getting this information about posting in meta being a requirement for tags. It's not a requirement per the [Drupal help center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) nor should it be.

Comment: @Clive with respect to "taking it on the chin," yes I'd already done that :) The problem is more practical: but I've been prevented from posting questions until the system's perceived quality of them increases.

Comment: Yes, I would not use _WordPress Development_ as example, since they have *php* as tag. Stack Exchange doesn't say how to add new tags, as it leaves that to each site. For sure, new users cannot know which tags have been tried in the past and which tags have been decided not to use anymore. That's why the suggestion of asking a question on _Drupal Answers meta_ makes sense. Yes, self-answered questions are welcome, but they are subject to the closing reasons as other questions. If a self-answered question is too broad, it will be closed as it isn't a self-answered question.

Comment: Also, it's probable that the expectations for self-answered questions are higher than for other questions, but this is understandable. If a user is going to post a self-answered question, the question should give enough details for any user to answer it; it should also give more details, since the question is being posted for a specific case for which the user found a solution. It cannot be a vague question like _How do I create a view for nodes?_ Also the answer should be detailed enough, as it's an answer for a specific case for which the user find a solution.

Comment: @kiamlaluno perhaps php isn't a terribly useful tag, but that's no more reason to write off the site's value (let alone equivalence) than it is to write off the Drupal site for its ubiquitously abused (7, 8, 9) tags.

Comment: @kiamlaluno With respect to "Stack Exchange" tag guidelines, I'm not sure what's pertinent about this, this site's guidelines are already clear, that posting in meta is no part of the process of introducing them. If you have ideas about making tag guidelines more restrictive than what is written in the help center, I suggest you create a meta topic to discuss, and edit the help documents to reflect the approach of those voting on them.

Comment: @kiamlaluno yes, if a question is too broad, and perhaps the views question is legitimately too broad, that is a perfectly valid reason for closing/deletion. However, leymannx specifically referenced answering your own questions as perceived "gaming the system" as justification for downvotes, when this is a practice actively encouraged by the general community and the site's founder. Also the idea that self-answered questions should be held to a higher standard is an interesting proposal, though I've never seen it documented.

Comment: It's pertinent because what you call site's guidelines are Stack Exchange guidelines. They cannot be edited and they cannot report details about a single community. The tags guidelines won't tell you that [tag:drupal-7] is a wrong tag for _Drupal Answers_, even if Stack Overflow has it.

Comment: What @leymannx said is not the reason for closing questions nor for down-voting. It's rather how low quality, self-answered, questions can be perceived from other users. Users could find that suspicious, in the same way they would find suspicious, for example, that a user asks low quality questions which are then answered from the same user who gets the answer accepted even if there are better answers.

Comment: @kiamlaluno by your own definition (not that I agree with it,) it seems you've contradicted your own statement: "Stack Exchange doesn't say how to add new tags." The Drupal Answers site's Help Center does in fact say *exactly* [how to add new tags](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags): _"Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created."_ And it says nothing about any requirements to post in meta. Perhaps the reason why these rules aren't allowed to be edited is that "what's good for the goose is good for the gander," so to speak.

Comment: I didn't contradict myself. _enter a new tag with your question and it will be created_ just says how to create a tag, but it doesn't say every tag is correct. The _simply_ at the beginning of the sentence just means _it is simple as_; it doesn't mean _This is what you only need to do to create a tag; you don't need to discuss the validity of the tag you added with other users._

Comment: It cannot, because the page that describes the [_create new tag_](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege says _you feel you can make a strong case that your question does cover a new topic_, where _you can make a strong case_ means you need to make a strong case when somebody debates the necessity of the new tag you added.

Comment: None of the guidelines/documentation found on a site, which are the same for every Stack Exchange site, says which tags are wrong, nor does it says where to make a strong case for a tag, nor if that should be done before creating a tag. That's exactly my point: Those details are left to the communities behind each site. I would go even further: There are Stack Exchange sites where some comments are considered acceptable, even if the page for the [_comment everywhere_](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege says the purpose of comments isn't that.

Comment: Nope... You won't find a documentation/guideline page common to every Stack Exchange that lists any tag that should be avoided. On the contrary, the privilege page for creating tags explicitly says _make a strong case_.

Comment: I didn't understand why this question on meta was downvoted so I upvoted. I usually try not to downvote a question that is probably going to be closed anyway as I also think it unfairly punishes new users trying to gain enough reputation to comment and review on their own.

Comment: I generally agree with most of the sentiment here. This topic probably should be asked as 2 different topics, since they're likely to have different comments/solutions.

Comment: Re: downvotes, I really wish the site would only allow a downvote with a justification in the form of constructive criticism comment or some other non-unilateral action.  Downvotes can be "unclear or not useful" too. Outside the obvious "here's my stack trace, now why doesn't it work?" type Q's, it seems like many Q's get downvotes without any explicit reasoning why it's "not researched, unclear, not useful."

Comment: @mradcliffe – Voting on Meta is for saying Agree/Disagree.

Comment: @leymannx You might benefit from reading ["Getting to Know Stack Overflow's Voting Culture"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251487/getting-to-know-stack-overflows-voting-culture) "On Meta, users generally vote based on their perception of the quality of the post (well researched/high value/interesting/correct) or, absent quality issues, if the user believes that the post contains a proposal, the premise of the post (agreement)." This post is not a proposal.

Comment: @ShawnConn It would be hard to justify an unjustified downvote, as is the case of the "good question" examples I'd cited in this meta post. And as I said, I wouldn't be spending time in meta on any of this just to vent frustration, but I've been banned from asking new questions as a result of this site dysfunction.

Comment: Voting is a balanced system - you can't force people to justify their downvotes without also forcing them to justify their upvotes. It wouldn't be sustainable in any practical sense, and who's going to police it? If my justification is _i don't like spaghetti_, what then? Voting _is_ different on meta @glenviewjeff, the help text you're citing doesn't cover the reality. People typically vote on any meta post based on whether they agree with the premise or not.

Answer (score 2):

Re: Tags. DA has an odd idiomatic way of enforcing tag usage which looks to be the result of various interpretations of the SE guidelines.

The gatekeeping process being an explicit meta-discussion seems like an oddly insular process to me and doesn't look like it has been done for many tags (FWIW, I've only ever seen this done for [version tags](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=7) so perhaps there was other discussions I missed.)

It also seems to have created a situation where tagging doesn't help with the subject matter at hand. For example, look at the tag inventory:

- A tag for [`rng`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rng) (a module 100's of installs) but no tag for [`pathauto`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathauto)(a module 100K's of installs)?
- A tag for [`acquia-dev-desktop`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acquia-dev-desktop), but no tag for any modern docker-based local dev tools? (e.g. [`lando`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lando), [`docksal`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/docksal))
- A tag for [`iis`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iis)(?), but no tag for the web servers mostly used with Drupal (e.g. [`apache`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache), [`nginx`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nginx))
- A tag for [`services`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/services), but no tag for the 3 newer D8 API modules created in the last 4 years? ([`core-rest`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/core-rest), [`jsonapi`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jsonapi), [`graphql`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphql))

Comment: Lots of useful tag suggestions in here. 