# Create [mimemail] tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

I am the maintainer of the [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) module and I would like to add a [mimemail](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mimemail) tag here on Drupal Answers in order to better support this module. There are years of questions about Mime Mail here on Drupal Answers, with many good responses, but this information is of limited use without a tag to unify this knowledge.

On the list of most-used Drupal modules, https://www.drupal.org/project/usage, Mime Mail ranks 75, with about 90,000 users, or about 9% of all Drupal users.

Other contributed modules have their own tags, and these modules range from the very popular (e.g, Webform, which is the 8th most popular module) to the not-very popular (e.g. Group, which ranks number 540 on the list). I don't see why my new tag was rejected - it's clearly useful and well-within the accepted use for tags.

All the documentation for StackExchange says that to create a new tag you first have to have enough reputation (which I now do), and then you just add the tag to a post, which will create the tag (subject to review).

But when I did this my edits were rejected with the form response "New tags only get introduced after being discussed on Meta Drupal Answers."

So in addition to discussing the tag here on Meta Drupal Answers as requested, perhaps in the future that form response could provide a link to Meta Drupal Answers (which is something I didn't know about ...), so that people requesting a tag know where to post?

AND perhaps you can fix the Drupal Answers documentation to mention that you don't follow the normal StackExchange procedure for adding a tag?

AND perhaps rather than outright rejecting new tags, with a rejection that isn't very visible (does not show up in the inbox, for example, or on the recent activity summary page), the reviewers could automatically open an issue for that tag?

In fact, I would think that the top 100 modules (or some similar criteria) would *automatically* get tags, or at least automatically be approved for tags.

Likewise, it seems that every post here in Meta Drupal Answers *requires* a tag - how about a tag for new tag requests? I tagged this as "feature-request" for lack of a better option, but if you're going to require all tag request be made in Meta Drupal Answers then you should have a tag to identify these expected requests, in order to streamline review and processing.

Comment: Tags don't need to be discussed on meta to be added (although meta is the place to discuss tags in a general sense) - do you mind sharing where you got that information from? Please feel free to suggest the tag again and ping me the URL, it'll get approved. We don't have an auto-approval process or a list of pre-approved tags or anything like that, but barring an awkward name clash or some such, you're probably right that we'd expect to see individual tags for the top _n_ modules, sure

Comment: @Clive – They got the information from me, because that's how it used to be with kiamlaluno. When I added new tags, kiamlaluno removed them. So I started a discussion on Meta and then they got created. That's why there are so many "Create [foobar] tag" posts here on Meta in which you also already participated. And what's also been discussed in https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3845/15055.

Comment: The issue is that there have been many new users who created new tags, even the ones that we decided not to use during the beta phase, and we have had few users who edited the wrong tags away. Posting a question on the meta site doesn't seem wrong, and it is something users are used to do since the beta phase. It's not that graduate sites stop using the meta site.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the meta site is used to ask for the removal of tags, when in most of the cases it's too late for doing something that doesn't require users with higher permissions. Instead of reaching that point, asking for a tag before using it seems less problematic, considering also it's what users are used to do since the beta phase.

Comment: What happened to all the comments that used to be here? There were maybe 20 additional comments that no longer show up.

Comment: They obviously got purged. Probably because off-topic. Clive suggested to create a new Meta question about the tag creation process.